# How to get 5 characters before and after?

Tags: php, regex

I need get

`bbish` `name3` `more`

`bbish` `name4` `more`

```
$p = '%<a\s+href="my-anchor-name3"\s*>(?:.*)</a>%im';
$s = 'some rubbish
<a href="my-anchor-name1">name</a>more rubbish
more rubbish<a href="my-anchor-name2">name2</a>more rubbish
more rubbish<a href="my-anchor-name3">name3</a>more rubbish
more rubbish<a href="my-anchor-name3">name4</a>more rubbish
more rubbish<a href="my-anchor-name5">name5</a>more rubbish';
$out = preg_match_all($p, $s, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry... what? Where is the output you are getting? Where are you trying to "get" 5 characters? Before and after _what_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what am I doing wrong?

You're not instructing PHP to do what you have indicated that you want to do, is the main flaw.

---

#### Problems

- You did not create an array into which to deposit the matches;
- You're not capturing any backreferences;
- Your capture inside the `a` tag is *greedy*;
- I suspect that you don't really want to restrict your `href` value like that;
- Your HTML input is *very* restricted, because [you're using regular expressions to parse HTML.... grrrrr!!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) *

---

#### Fix

Try this:

```
<?php
$matches = Array();
$p = '%(.{0,5})<a\s+href="my-anchor-name3"\s*>(.*?)</a>(.{0,5})%imm';
$s = 'some rubbish
<a href="my-anchor-name1">name</a>more rubbish
more rubbish<a href="my-anchor-name2">name2</a>more rubbish
more rubbish<a href="my-anchor-name3">name3</a>more rubbish
more rubbish<a href="my-anchor-name3">name4</a>more rubbish
more rubbish<a href="my-anchor-name5">name5</a>more rubbish';
$out = preg_match_all($p, $s, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => bbish<a href="my-anchor-name3">name3</a>more 
            [1] => bbish
            [2] => name3
            [3] => more 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => bbish<a href="my-anchor-name3">name4</a>more 
            [1] => bbish
            [2] => name4
            [3] => more 
        )

)
```

[Live demo.](http://www.ideone.com/5wtcr)

---

#### Further work

You may wish to further restrict what characters may be eaten up in those backreferences.

And if you don't want to limit your `href` values the way you are (and you're doing it in quite a confusing way at present):

```
$p = '%(.{0,5})<a\s+href="my-anchor-name\d+"\s*>(.*?)</a>(.{0,5})%imm';
```

[Like this.](http://www.ideone.com/lvd4J)

---

* The real answer here is that you should not be using regular expressions to parse HTML, which is **a well-known fact**. Marc has the solution that you *should* be using.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use regexes. Period. it's trivial to extract text nodes before/after a particular node's position using DOm functions.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom-loadHTML($html);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$res = $xp->query('//a[starts-with(@href, "my-anchor-name")]');
$out = array()
foreach($res as $a) {
    $previous = substr($a->previousSibling->nodeValue, -5);
    $next = substr($a->nextSibling->nodeValue, -5);
    $here = $a->nodeValue;

    $out[] = $previous . $here . $next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not really giving enough data to make this work exactly, but based on the sample data above, this should work:

```
$p = '/(.{5})<a\shref="my\-anchor\-(name[0-9]+)">.*</a>(.{5})/';
if (preg_match($p, $s, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
  echo "Matches found.";
} else {
  echo "Matches not found.";
}
```

Then simply handle all the search hits in the `$matches` array as you please.

Comment: Your `<a>` matching is broken.

Comment: Ahh yes, thanks. Edited it. I didn't test this, just threw it together real quick as an example.

Comment: You're now missing one of the outputs, and I think not supporting multi-line input properly. I could go on. :)

Answer (score -1):

You could prepend and append something like this to the regex: `(.{5})`.

Thus:

```
$p = '%(.{5})<a\s+href="my-anchor-name3"\s*>(?:.*)</a>(.{5})%im';
```